# How does that for loop doesn't goes out of bounds with unidimensional array in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays

Take a look :

```
int[] v = new int[10];    
for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < v.length; j++) {
                if (v[i] > v[j]) {
                    aux = v[i];
                    v[i] = v[j];
                    v[j] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
```

**This works perfecly.** But can someone explain how?

How this array DOES **NOT** goes out of bounds even if I start `j` with `i + 1` ? How does this works?

Comment: Because `j < v.length`.

Comment: The loop condition `j < v.length` is checked before each iteration of the for loop.  So it *is* out of bounds and just ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused the initialization with condition. The syntax for for loop() is-

```
  for(initialization; condition; updation)
    { 
    statement(s)
       }
```

So even if you start j from 1 ( j = i+1 and initial value of i = 0), j will update only till it is equal to the length of the array v i.e., 10. So the moment, j = 10 ( when i = 9), the control will come out of j for loop() and when it will transfer to i for loop(), i will be updated to 10, thus meeting it's condition and moving the control out of i for loop() also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go back to basics on for loops

a for loop can be defined as `for(before starting;continue when true;do at end of pass))`

So it doesn't matter what your start value is, as soon as j is equal to v.length it will stop. It just does 1 less loop that if you started at i.

Comment: I don't need to go **back** to basics..I'm a beginner in programming

Comment: Haha that's ok! This link looks pretty good: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_for_loops.html

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops are made up of a variable to keep track, the condition and the iteration. In your code, the condition of the for loops states that the variable that is keeping track cannot go past the length of v. Therefore, during the sort (because that's what the code is), the inner loop compares all of v's values using j as the index to swap if they meet the if condition. The outer loop is just there to make sure that each index of v is checked and are in the right place.